# Installing Adt 22.3 offline

Tags: eclipse, installation, repository, adt, offline

I cant connect to the internet from my work computer and i need to install the new ADT(22.3.0)
i've downloaded the ADT zip file from the android developers website 
and on eclipse i went to HELP->INSTALL NEW SOFTWARS
clicked add and then chosed the zip file and i get this error message:
Unable to read repository at jar:file/*The file path*/content.xml

I have no idea how to fix it. i looked on a lot of other people posts and on google and still couldnt find an answer

my eclipse version is Indigo service release 2.

maybe there is something i need to configure in the eclipse settings?
any help will be much appriciated.

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the ZIP file hasn't been corrupted. You shouldn't get it once the ZIP file is good.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. This is a old question so it might be that it dont get your attention! Just for your info!